# gnuplot: label overflowing outside canvas isn't drawn

Tags: gnuplot

I'm putting labels on top (offset by 10) of histogram bars like this:

```
plot "hist.txt" using 1:2 with boxes ls 1, "hist.txt" using 1:($2+10):(sprintf("%.1f%%",$2)) with labels
```

When the bar value is 87%, it draws the label.

When the bar value is 92%, the label isn't drawn, probably since there isn't enough space left. How do I tell it to draw the label anyway, and I don't mind if it would overflow the intended canvas size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you limit the range of the y-axis to 0~100, the y-value of 92 + 10(= 102) will not be drawn because it exceeds the maximum value of yrange.

It works well if you use `with labels offset 0, first 10` as the plot style specification instead of shifting the position of the label in `using`.

```
set key noautotitle

set tmargin screen 0.85
set xrange [0:11]
set yrange [0:100]

plot "hist.txt" using 1:2 with boxes ls 1, \
     "hist.txt" using 1:2:(sprintf("%.1f%%",$2)) with labels offset 0,first 10
```

Sample "hist.txt" is,

```
1 30
2 60
3 87
4 92
5 50
6 20
7 10
8 30
9 50
10 40
```

[image]